# IIS SSL Certificate "Export" option missing

Tags: ssl, iis

Windows 2016 Server, IIS 10.

I have created an SSL certificate using WACS (Formerly Letsencrypt Win Simple)
Everything works fine.

Except, when I right click on the certificate from IIS, the "Export" option is missing.

Is this due to anything that I might have done in the certificate creation, that makes it un-exportable? Is there any way to try exporting it from command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: "PrivateKeyExportable" needs to be set to "true" Settings.json configuration file